# Steady state customer behavior in queuing model -- Numerical Optimization

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

With the following code I try to calculate the steady-state equilibrium waiting time at two different queues. A fraction `tau` of users turns away entriely, a fraction `q1` waits at the first queue and the remainder at the second queue.
Customers are waiting time sensitive and only wait, if their expected utility `10 - 1 WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] >= 0`.
For inutition: If `tau=1` waiting time would go towards infinity in steady state.

I try to identify the maximum share of users that may queue up.

```
  WtMM1[q1_, lambda_, mu_] := (lambda q1)/(mu^2 - lambda mu q1)
    
    WtMMn[q1_, lambda_, mu_, n_] := 1/( mu n + lambda (-1 + 10 q1) + (E^((lambda - 10 lambda q1)/
       mu) (mu n + lambda (-1 + 10 q1))^2 ExpIntegralE[1 - n, (lambda - 10 lambda q1)/mu])/mu)

    lambda = 100000; mu = 1;

    NMaximize[{tau,   
      WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] == WtMMn[q1, lambda tau, mu, 5]  &&   
       0 <= (1 - q1*10) <= 1 && 0 <= tau <= 1  && 
       10 - 1 WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] >= 0  && 
       WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] > 0 && 0 <= tau <= 1 } ,   {q1, tau}]
```

Somehow my code does not find the maximum tau, of which I guess that it leads to `10 - 1 WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] == 0`.

I think it has sth. to do with the integrated equilibrium between queues, specifically `WtMM1[q1, lambda tau, mu] == WtMMn[q1, lambda tau, mu, 5]`
Did I mess up the synthax in my code? Is there a nice way to disentangle the two problems and thus help mathematica?

For a somewhat less complex problem it works:

```
NMaximize[{tau, 
  10 - 1 Wtcoord[tau lambda, mu, 15] >= 0  && 
   Wtcoord[tau lambda, mu, 15] > 0 && 0 <= tau <= 1} ,   {tau}]
```

Here the answer is relatively accurate.

Comment: `Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: This message means that `NMinimize` failed to find a feasible point for the optimization problem. This might mean that there is no such point or that the feasible set is hard to make out.

Comment: Thx Henrik. But is there a way to help my code to find a solution. It should not be such a hard problem.

Comment: Well, if there is no feasible point then the problem has no solution. So please check the constraints. Another issue could be that the `ExpIntegralE` epression returns nonreal values sometimes. So please check whether this expression is set up correctly. I cannot help you with that because I am not proficient in the underlying stochastics.

Comment: Hi Henrik, there must be a feasible solution, because for tau=0 all side conditions are fulfilled. I also added a more minimalistic example, which probably shows that the problem does not lie in the $ExpIntegralE$. Perhaps there is a way to disentangle the problems?